# Python 2 ordinal not in range on join

Tags: unicode, python-2.x

When I do

`u','.join([u'\u4e8c\u6797', unicode(10)])`

it fails with `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)`. All three items in the list are of type unicode.

Why is it trying to encode in ascii? I don't want it to convert to ascii string. How do I avoid it?

Comment: Works for me. Dig deeper.

Comment: Oh yeah I was trying to print it, or write to file.

Answer (score 0):

Not really enough information, since it works just fine as displayed:

```
>>> u','.join([u'\u4e8c\u6797', unicode(10)])
u'\u4e8c\u6797,10'
```

But my crystal ball says you are trying to print it in some manner:

```
>>> print u','.join([u'\u4e8c\u6797', unicode(10)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\dev\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: character maps to <undefined>
```

The reason is, at least on my system, is the terminal uses `cp437` encoding and can't encode the Unicode characters in that encoding.

Or more likely writing to a file or pipe:

```
>>> with open('out.txt','w') as f:
...   f.write(u','.join([u'\u4e8c\u6797', unicode(10)]))
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Files have to be told the encoding, such as UTF-8, or they default to ASCII:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> with open('out.txt','w') as f:
...   f.write(u','.join([u'\u4e8c\u6797', unicode(10)]).encode('utf8'))
...
>>>  # SUCCESS!
```

Comment: Your crystal ball is correct. In fact I first encountered the error when writing to file. Then I try to print it to see what gives. I open the file with `fdout = codecs.open(outputFileName, 'w', "utf-8")` with the codecs module.

Comment: And the [u'\u4e8c\u6797', unicode(10)] is a simplified example of what I did, not the original problem. I just noticed that this one went through when writing to file. Let me check the original case again.